# Torify an arbitrary application?

Tags: termux, tor

After setting up a self-hosted Nextcloud over tor, I am trying to synchronize an Android Calendar app with it. On Ubuntu I was able to `torify` `vdirsyncer` and run `khal` as a terminal calendar. However, on android I would prefer a GUI, and I have not yet been able to install `vdirsyncer` in `termux`.

I tried installing Nextcloud developer app and connecting it directly with the `some_onion.onion` server, however, as expected that did not work. Hence, I would like to ask:

How can one torify an arbitrary application on Android (using e.g. LineageOS or /e/OS)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what the [orbot](https://guardianproject.info/fdroid/) app does.

To download the app from [f-droid](https://f-droid.org/) one:

1. First installs the f-droid `apk` from f-droid.org.
2. Next, in that f-droid app on the phone, one can go to: `settings> (My Apps)> Repositories> (Enable) Guardian Project Official Releases`.
3. (Update the repositories with: `back> Updates> pull the window down to do an update of the repositories).
4. Next, search in the market place search for: `orbot` and select the one that **literally** says: `Orbot: Tor for Android`. If that is not in there, verify you enabled the `Guardian Project Official Releases` and that you updated the fdroid market place/repositories.
5. Install the Orbot app.
6. Open the Orbot app.
7. Enable "VPN Mode"
8. Select "tor enabled apps" and choose which app you want to go over tor.
9. Back in the main Orbot screen/window, press/hold "start" until you see a green onion.
10. Now you can go to your app, e.g. Nextcloud and enter your `https://some_onion.onion` domain, to make the Nextcloud connect to your self-hosted Nextcloud server.

This is marvellous work by the Guardian Project I think. I am amazed by how well it works, and have not automated this yet through adb.